# Двоеточие вместо "потому что"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, двоеточие, бсп

**Парень уже не кричал: он потерял сознание.**

В этом предложении уместно ли двоеточие (так как это БСП)?

Answer (score 4):

Да, вроде все по [правилам](https://therules.ru/colon/): двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует другое, содержащее основание или раскрывающее **причину** того, о чём говорится в первом предложении (между частями можно вставить союзы *так как, потому что*).

Но ситуация, описываемая в предложении, не является нейтральной — она эмоциональна, нестандартна. Я бы поставила тире — для придания предложению выразительности.

**Парень уже не кричал — он потерял сознание.**

**P. S.** В последнее время эти знаки часто употребляются параллельно, то есть в одних и тех же случаях может ставиться как тире, так и двоеточие. Например:
*Конечно, он изменился **(: —)** сгорбился, поседел, с морщинками в уголках рта;

Эти слова при нем не произносите **(: —)** может обидеться.*

**P. P. S.** 1. Дело в том, что на выбор знака очень часто влияет предыдущий контекст и ви́дение самого автора. 2. Предложения, представленные мною в постскриптуме, приведены в качестве примеров в справочнике Д. Э. Розенталя.

[§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания. Двоеточие — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189)

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, значит, если поставить тире, это не будет считаться ошибкой? А например, в предложении такого же типа " Проснулся он на снегу: на него вылили ведро холодной воды" тоже следует заменить двоеточие на тире?

Comment: А здесь вообще нет причины и следствия, логика нарушена. Проснулся на снегу, потому что вылили ведро воды? Как это?!

Comment: Он проснулся: на него вылили ведро холодной воды. Так точнее. Он проснулся, потому что на него вылили ведро воды.

Comment: Здесь _есть_ причина: он бы и дальше кричал, да сознание потерял от боли и т. п.

Comment: Так значит, что уместнее тире или двоеточие?)

Comment: А вот с примером номер один в постскриптуме не соглашусь. Это обобщение, поэтому наиболее нормативным вариантом будет двоеточие.

Answer (score 3):

В БСП ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения имеет значение причины, обоснования, что проверяется возможностью подстановки союзов ***так как, потому что: Ответить Миллер не успел: лодка вошла в буруны (Пауст.); Настена извелась вся, но подгонять свекра не решалась: нельзя было показать, что ей зачем-то нужна лодка (Расп.)***

См: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.